# Magendo Move Send To Friend To a Tab Under Product View

Tags: php, xml, magento, magento-1.5

I'm trying to display the send to friend form under a tab in Product View.

I inserted the following code under /app/design/frontend/default/mytemplate/layout/catalog.xml

```
<action method="addTab" translate="title">
    <alias>send-friend</alias>
    <title>Send Friends</title>
    <block>sendfriend/send</block>
    <template>sendfriend/send.phtml</template>
</action>
```

I inserted the code inside:

```
<block type="catalog/product_view_tabs" name="product.info.tabs" as="info_tabs" template="catalog/product/view/tabs.phtml" >
```

Problem is that it isn't working... I get a message from the browser saying "too many redirects" and nothing is shown!

I have a couple of other tabs that I added in similar fashion. The other ones work fine.

Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the code I inserted in the question was correct!

The problem was that every time I clicked on a product, Magento would redirect me to the same page instead of opening the requested product page.

After activating the error logging in Magento Admin -> System -> Configuration -> Developer

I noticed an error in /magento_install_path/var/log/exception.log saying something like 'Mage_Core_Exception please define a valid cookie instance' (my magento lang is not English so I don't know the exact error in English).

After this it was pretty easy. Just go to System -> Configuration. Under Catalog choose Send Friends and choose "IP Address" in "Limit sending to"!

Hope this helps someone.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to move an existing block you need to use the 'unsetChild' and 'insert' methods with appropriate references to the section of the app being referenced. The example code I have below does an unset of the Poll block from the right column, and moves it to the left column after the 'catalog.leftnav' block. This was used with the Professional version, but still should be useful as a starting point for any version. You may need to turn on the debug options to see block names etc, combined with looking at class names etc in firebug. If it isn't a move, the insert syntax, portion of the example should be useful.

Let me know if you need further assistance.

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <reference name='right'>
            <action method='unsetChild'><name>right.poll</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name='left'>
            <action method='insert'>
                <name>right.poll</name>
                <sibling>catalog.leftnav</sibling>
            </action>
        </reference>

    </default>
</layout>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I'm not trying to move existing blocks though. In my product page I have a link to another page which will then send to friends (this is base install) but I want to have that form in the product page. I do exactly the same with reviews with ease...